# Microsoft Visual Studio VB.NET , could not find file error

Tags: visual-studio-2022

[image: sample picture of the error]

I have encountered an error of ' Could not find file [file path] ' and is making my build fail.
I have tried to troubleshoot myself and find solutions but to no avail hoping that I can find a resolution here.

I apologize if my posting format is wrong again, I am a student and not a full time programmer.

I deleted a file in the resource folder before deleting the picturebox in the design and it caused this error making me unable to view the design or run the program at all.

I have tried restoring the file but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am using VS2022

Comment: Delete resource, add it again. clean solution. or better yet, close visual studio, delete folder `obj` and then reopen project